# Python "as" keyword ignored in Listings

Tags: listings

Following code cant highlight **as** keyword. What am I doing wrong?
Shouldn't **as** be bold like **import**?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{morekeywords={as}}

\title{Python listings}
\author{me}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
Python example

\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python]
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
An animated image
"""
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
\end{lstlisting}

done with the example.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Using `\lstset{otherkeywords={as}}` seems to work.  From the documentation it appears that `otherkeywords` is intended to be used for keywords that may contain other characters or begin with numbers, so perhaps it is a bug that `morekeywords` did not work.

Comment: I can confirm that `otherkeywords` works. I didn't find a valid reason (in listings documentation) to `morekeywords` ignore 'as', thus it seems it's a bug. Where can I report it? e-mail to the maintainer?

Comment: For bugs it is best to email the package maintainer, but I'd wait some time to see if someone provides an explanation here.  But still good that you posted the question in case someone else encounters a similar issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `morekeyword=as` option works if you declare it *after* telling `listings` that the language to be used is Python:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python,morekeywords=as]
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
An animated image
"""
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It's perhaps better to define an own environment for Python:

```
\lstnewenvironment{Python}[1][]
  {\lstset{language=Python,
           morekeywords=as,
           #1}%
  }
  {}
```

so that it will be possible to write

```
\begin{Python}
<Python code>
\end{Python}
```

possibly giving other local options, say

```
\begin{Python}[basicfamily=\ttfamily]
<Python code>
\end{Python}
```

Comment: Thanks! It's helpful, but it's still a bug in listings?  How to implement `morekeywords` to use it with `\lstinputlisting[language=Python]{python_code.py}`?

Comment: @sivic Why should be this considered a bug? The `morekeywords` are set on a per language basis. You may want to add `as` in Python, but not in C++ (just a random language).

Comment: @sivic The only way I see to add something to a predefined language is to define a new one: `\lstdefinelanguage{sPython}[]{Python}{morekeywords=as}`.

Comment: Yes! Defining a "new" (copy) language is nice way to solve this. Now I can put all stuff defined in `\lstset` in `\lstdefinelanguage`?