# Mixing multiple programming languages with different styles in same document

Tags: listings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Defining `lstset` parameters for multiple languages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45711/defining-lstset-parameters-for-multiple-languages)

What's the easiest way to include code, using listings, from more programming languages?

```
\lstset{ %
  language=Python,
  basicstyle=\footnotesize\sffamily,
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray}\sffamily,
  stepnumber=1,
  numbersep=5pt,
  backgroundcolor=\color{lstbckcolor},
  showspaces=false,
  showstringspaces=false,
  showtabs=false,
  frame=top, frame=bottom,
  rulecolor=\color{black},
  tabsize=2,
  captionpos=t,
  breaklines=true,
  breakatwhitespace=false,
  title=\lstname,
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
  stringstyle=\color{mauve},
  escapeinside={\%*}{*)}, 
  morekeywords={as,from,odeset} 
}

\begin{document}

\section{Examples}
Python example:
\lstinputlisting[language=Python]{python_code.py}
Matlab example
\lstinputlisting[language=Matlab]{spremnik.m}
One more Python example:
\lstinputlisting[language=Python]{python_code2.py}

\end{document}
```

The style of listing is same for matlab and python, including keywords (why if define python is defined as language in `\lstset`?).
How to define another `\lstset` for Matlab?

Comment: I probvably got the answer in another post [[link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73912/python-as-keyword-ignored-in-listings/73946#comment157502_73946)] using `\lstdefinelanguage` to define a new language with its own keywords, style, etc.