# Use multiple languages using lstset?

Tags: listings, texshop

My MWE :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[lmargin=3.81cm,tmargin=2.54cm,rmargin=2.54cm,bmargin=2.52cm]{geometry}
\linespread{1.5}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}

\lstset{frame=tb,
  language=Matlab,
  aboveskip=3mm,
  belowskip=3mm,
  showstringspaces=false,
  columns=flexible,
  basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{black},
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
  stringstyle=\color{mauve},
  breaklines=true,
  breakatwhitespace=true
  tabsize=3
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
 e=1;e2=1;e3=1 %%control variable for ON mode
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

I have a Python code that I want to add, but the language set currently is only for matlab. How can I define it for two languages ?

Comment: See possible duplicate: [Defining \`lstset\` parameters for multiple languages](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45711) and the linked dupes [Mixing multiple programming languages with different styles in same document](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74007) and [Syntax highlighting for different programming languages](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/106538)

Comment: @hpesoj626 Thanks but the question was already answered by Mario, there wasn't a need to close this.

Comment: You might be interested in the [`matlab-prettifier`](https://bitbucket.org/Jubobs/matlab-prettifier) package; see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158816/21891).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set this when you input the file, e.g.:

```
\lstinputlisting[language=Matlab]{matlabfile.m}

\lstinputlisting[language=python]{pythonfile.py}
```

For more information visit the [package documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf)

Comment: But im copy-pasting the code into my tex file, would this still work ?

Comment: If you are copying just part of your code, wouldn't the `verbatim` environment be more useful to you?

Comment: Actually the method you proposed here is much better and more organised, i'll use this instead :D thanks !

Comment: The main advantage of using this is that don't have to update the code in LaTeX if you make any changes to the file.  The argument of the `lstinputlistings` command points directly to the file, so any change made to it will reflect in your pdf output.

Comment: Yeah, thanks alot for that ... Regarding the settings in preamble (following `\lstset{frame=tb,`), are these still needed though ?

Comment: well, the command `\lstset` is for the settings that are going to affect both files, so "frame" there is affecting both the matlab and the python file

Comment: Ahh now I understand this better. Thank you very much.